# Nullifying the shahada

Tags: shahada

Salam aleikum. 
I am a revert that took the shahada awhile ago. 
I follow the Sunni direction og Islam. 
The Sheikh i took the shahada in front of is a sufi. 
I recently got told that being a sufi nullyfies the shahada because they places mediums between themself and Allah (subhana wa ta’ala). They explained that this is said by Muhammad ibn Abdul Wahhab.

Should i take the shahada once again?

Comment: So it seems you think that due to the sufi witnesses your shahfah is not accepted or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Yes. I that is what i have Bern told. But i dont mind that at all